# Using an async command from a cog across multiple cogs - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I currently have a cog with some commands in it - for example, a message clear command:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['kl'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(self, ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    if True: await ctx.send(str(int(amount)) + ' messages have been deleted.', delete_after=5)
```

And within another cog, I have a command which calls this command:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(ctx, message)

#Some conditions to look for

#If conditions are true, then execute the following line:

await self.clear(ctx, amount)
```

But when I run my code, I get this error: `'OBJECT' object has no attribute 'clear'`

What I've tried:

-Adding `from TARGETCOGNAME import clear`, but that gives me `discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.COGNAME' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clear'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, please supply some code with any helpful suggestions - as I'm fairly new to Python and still learning :)

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I tried using `self.bot.commands`, but I ended up getting a massive dict of command objects:

`{<discord.ext.commands.core.Command object at 0x000001FF1F47C040>, <discord.ext.commands.core.Command object at 0x000001FF1F5DD060>, ...}`

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to import like that - you can only import the cog as a whole. However, if your bot is running, you might be able to invoke the command through `bot.get_command` (without any importing, which does avoid annoyances like circular imports).

Comment: How would I go about adding that to my cog? Do I put that at the top of the document, or do I write that for every time I call that command?

Comment: In your `on_message` command, try `print(client.get_command('clear'))` and see if it gives you the command object.

Comment: Nope, it just prints 'None'. I am using this within another cog, though - is self.bot.get_command('clear') valid syntax, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: It should work if the command is registered, even if it's in a cog. Maybe `self.bot.commands` has all of them, but that's unlikely

Comment: It does actually print a list of command objects when I do ``self.bot..commands``! But how would I actually run my specific ``clear`` command?

Comment: You should be able to use either `command.invoke` or `ctx.invoke` to run the callback behind the command. Or you can also make another method `_clear` that gets called by both commands (think of it like the internal implementation with two other things calling it).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get how I would call my ``clear`` command from the list of commands which ``self.bot.commands`` returns; could you please post an answer with some code if possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure because you said you couldn't `bot.get_command` it out. Mind [edit]ing the question to include the output of `bot.commands`?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: Maybe try printing their names `[cmd.name for cmd in bot.commands]`. The `clear` should be in there *somewhere* if you're able to run it in discord.

Comment: Yep, that worked; it prints out all my commands which are stored within cogs.

Comment: I suppose you're able to filter them out and sort of manually get that command - `[cmd for cmd in bot.commands if cmd.name == 'clear'][0]`

Comment: Mhm, I was able to do that just fine

Comment: You should be able to [`ctx.invoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=invoke#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoke) it. `ctx.invoke(that_command, amount=100)`

Comment: I tried doing that, but slicing to get the first item of the list collapses the command object into a name; when I try running that using ctx.invoke, I get: ``raise TypeError('Missing command to invoke.') from None``.

Comment: It shouldn't. You want `cmd for cmd in bot.commands`, not `cmd.name` I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in `self` in the place where you're calling THAT command like:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(ctx, self, message)

#Some conditions to look for

#If conditions are true, then execute the following line:

await self.clear(ctx, amount)
```